# Can't generate new app with Rails 3.0.6 or 3.0.7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

When I try to generate a new app with Rails 3.0.6 or 3.0.7 installed I just get the instructions for using the `rails` command. For some reason Rails seems to think that I have typed in the wrong syntax (which I haven't, of course). Everything works fine in 3.0.5 or lower, though. I run Ruby 1.9.2 and Ubuntu 10.04.

`rails new app`

Will result in:

```
Usage:
  rails new APP_PATH [options]

Options:
  -r, [--ruby=PATH]           # Path to the Ruby binary of your choice
                              # Default: /usr/local/bin/ruby
  -d, [--database=DATABASE]   # Preconfigure for selected database (options: mysql/oracle/postgresql/sqlite3/frontbase/ibm_db)
                              # Default: sqlite3
  -b, [--builder=BUILDER]     # Path to an application builder (can be a filesystem path or URL)
  -m, [--template=TEMPLATE]   # Path to an application template (can be a filesystem path or URL)
      [--dev]                 # Setup the application with Gemfile pointing to your Rails checkout
      [--edge]                # Setup the application with Gemfile pointing to Rails repository
      [--skip-gemfile]        # Don't create a Gemfile
  -O, [--skip-active-record]  # Skip Active Record files
  -T, [--skip-test-unit]      # Skip Test::Unit files
  -J, [--skip-prototype]      # Skip Prototype files
  -G, [--skip-git]            # Skip Git ignores and keeps

Runtime options:
  -f, [--force]    # Overwrite files that already exist
  -p, [--pretend]  # Run but do not make any changes
  -q, [--quiet]    # Supress status output
  -s, [--skip]     # Skip files that already exist

Rails options:
  -v, [--version]  # Show Rails version number and quit
  -h, [--help]     # Show this help message and quit

Description:
    The 'rails new' command creates a new Rails application with a default
    directory structure and configuration at the path you specify.

Example:
    rails new ~/Code/Ruby/weblog

    This generates a skeletal Rails installation in ~/Code/Ruby/weblog.
    See the README in the newly created application to get going.
```

Comment: Sounds like they have made app a reserved word and its not failing gracefully. Rails does create an app directory, it is possible something has been added to keep you from naming an app from a directory that exists in an app, try something like "rails new config" and see if it fails

Comment: "app" was just an example. "rails new my_app" fails just as much.

Comment: "rails new app" works fine for me. Rails 3.0.6, Ubuntu 11.04.

Comment: Yes, I bet it does. If everyone would've encountered this problem I would've got a lot more relevant search results :).

Comment: :) I'd suggest opening an issue on the rails github repository. Sorry to not be of any more help.

Comment: What happens if you run this: `$(which rails) new my_app`

Comment: I had the same problem with rails 3.0.7 and rubygems 1.8 on Os X 10.6, updating to 1.8.1 fixed it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try updating rubygems;

```
$ gem update --system
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems running `rvm rubygems current` breaks this, at least for me.
I ran the command as it was mentioned [here](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/issues/345) that it would get rid of all the deprecation warnings, running `gem update --system` fixes it, and brings back the deprecation warnings.